# What does "sudo chmod -R 777 /" do?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I did `sudo chmod -R 777 /` on our production server and everything got messed up. The hosted sites and API's stopped working, SSH said connection refused, it was a cyberpanel running cent os 7 and we couldn't even log into cyberpanel.

I thought that all users would have have all permissions on all files in the system and executed the command. I don't quite understand what went wrong.

Comment: HI @OroZoro. Go for the backup or last snapshot. Too much work to recover it and related security issues.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. CentOS 7 is not an official flavor of Ubuntu.

Comment: The question you probably should be asking is: WHY did you run `sudo chmod -R 777 /` on a production server?

Comment: `sudo chmod 777 -R /` makes every file and directory on the entire system world-readable, world-writable, and world-executable. And since `777` is equivalent to `0777`, it will also deactivate the setuid, setgid, and sticky bits. Your system is now completely de-immunised. Wipe and reinstall everything from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just messed up your system; time to reinstall.

Yes, theoretically you now have all permissions, but you lost all setuid, setgid and sticky bits. Apart from losing all security, of course. Doing that on a production server (!!) is the cherry on top.

You lost the ability to use `sudo`, `su` and probably a dozen other commands that you probably wanted to keep using.

Comment: I thought theoretically and acted, there wasn't any backup maintained, we had to reconfigure everything, to my fortune, there weren't any logs maintained so the culprit is unidentified :). Thanks for your answer.